# Sharing Altium Designer projects

Tags: altium

I am new to Altium Designer and electronics in general. I want to share my future Altium projects with others, for example, on GitHub. How I should organize a project to make it more "share-friendly"? So that anyone could simply download and use it, without any additional complications.

Of particular concern are library components. What if I use components from my own library in some project? Should I also share the library? Should I share separate SchLib and PcbLib or integrated IntLib? Maybe it would be best to create a project library from the schematic, as described [in this blog post](https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/creating-project-libraries-from-the-schematic)?

Comment: If you do create a Git repo yourself (which I believe personally still to be safer than to trust AD18 with it, opinion, not fact), beware of including too much clutter like the "history" and "preview" folder and all the generated reports like DRC reports and what not. Waste of space in your repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library components that are used are embedded in the schematic and PCB documents, so there is no need to create/extract a library. If the recipient has AD they can extract a library as easily as you can.

Of course you can share your own full library if you want but they can get quite large.

I would say to make it more share friendly, output and include documents that don't require AD such as .pdf schematics and .pdf PCB layouts and Gerbers and .xls BOM.

Comment: You mean that if I give you a project full of my custom-made components, you will be able to open and work with this project (i.e. change schematics, layout, etc.) without any problems? If so, then it makes everything much simpler!

Comment: You should only need to supply .PcbDoc, .SchDoc, and .PrjPcb files. Of course if there is a new component they will have to find it in their own libraries or create the symbol and footprint.

Comment: I forgot to ask about the fonts. Are they embedded or not?

Comment: Truetype fonts are optionally embedded (or they may be substituted if missing).  And you have to choose to have images embedded if they're loaded from a file (eg. for schematic symbols) otherwise they don't show up and you get a blank box with a link overtop.

Comment: I would certainly add output files if you want to be world-friendly, but I would not include them in the Git history, if you maintain a git repo independently. It's generally considered "bad form" to include generated material in versioning, as it very quickly bloats up the versioning history needlessly. You can post them somewhere else public as fixed releases and link to them from your README.md file.

Comment: @Asmyldof Wouldn't that vary a bit with the relative sizes? Usually the PDFs and especially the Gerbers/drill files are pretty tiny compared to the other files, less than 5%.

Comment: The main thing there is that every export will be "duplicate information" and not every export is necessarily a release. Anyway, you're probably right that it doesn't matter that much. I, and many others with me, consider it better practise to not include derivatives in Git as a standard operating principle, but it may not make as much a difference as I implied initially.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany when you say, "the recipient has AD they can extract a library as easily as you can" I am trying to do this via Design-->Make Integrated Library, but all the components in the schematics/pcb continue to refer to the original external source rather than the newly created integrated library. How can you extract this library and update all references to use this new local library rather than the one you don't have access to?

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this (but havent used so can't really comment)

https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Dlg-WizardArchiver((Project+Packager+Wizard))_AD